# Como recorrer dos arraylist en uno

Tags: vb

Tengo esta situación: cada vez que cargo un nombre y una edad los pongo en arraylist separados cada uno, luego de eso, quiero que me muestre los datos que cargue (nombre,edad), algo así como "la persona se llama ... y tiene ... anos"

A continuación,la subrutina donde hago eso.
Lo hice con dos for each, lo cual hace que los datos se repitan.

```vb
Sub MostrarListado(ByRef arrayNombre As ArrayList, ByRef arrayEdad As ArrayList)
            For Each nombre In arrayNombre
                For Each edad In arrayEdad
                    Console.WriteLine("La persona se llama: " & nombre)
                    Console.WriteLine("y tiene: " & edad & " " & "anos")
                Next
            Next
        End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?, por cierto, recorrer con ciclos anidados es para desplazarse en matrices por renglones o columnas.

Comment: edite la publicación, al hacer con dos for each los datos se repiten y no se muestran correctamente

Comment: Porque lo estas recorriendo como matriz.. y vos queres uno a uno.. o sea el primero de uno con el primero del otro.. usa un for comun y entra por indice y listo el problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si haces un doble `For Each` mostraras cada nombre con todas las edades almacenadas y no con la edad que le corresponde.
Tu código asume que los dos `ArrayList` contienen el mismo número de `Items` y que a cada nombre le corresponde la edad almacenada en el `ArrayList arrayEdad` en el mismo indice, asumiendo que esti se cumple siempre, el siguiente código debe funcionar bien, te recomiendo que lo pruebes y me comentas el resultado.

```
Sub MostrarListado(ByRef arrayNombre As ArrayList, ByRef arrayEdad As ArrayList)
    Dim index As Int32
    index = 0
    For Each nombre In arrayNombre
        Console.WriteLine("La persona se llama: " & nombre)
        Dim edad As String
        edad = arrayEdad.Item(index)
        Console.WriteLine("y tiene: " & edad & " " & "anos")
        index = index + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Edición: A continuación te coloco otra variante haciendo un lazo `For`.

```
Sub MostrarListado(ByRef arrayNombre As ArrayList, ByRef arrayEdad As ArrayList)
    For index As Int32 = 0 To arrayNombre.Count
        Dim nombre As String = arrayNombre.Item(index)
        Console.WriteLine("La persona se llama: " & nombre)
        Dim edad As String = arrayEdad.Item(index)
        Console.WriteLine("y tiene: " & edad & " " & "anos")
    Next
End Sub
```